# When is it more appropriate to move logic from the VM to a custom binding in Knockout?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I would like to display the current time in my Knockout web app and have it update every second. There are 2 solutions that I'm considering and I'm trying to decide which approach is more appropriate.

**Approach 1**: View Model logic

JS:

```
vm.currentTime = ko.observable(Date.now());
setInterval(function () {
  vm.currentTime(Date.now());
}, 1000);
```

HTML:

```
<span data-bind="text: currentTime"></span>
```

**Approach 2**: Custom Binding

JS:

```
vm.getTime = function () {
  return Date.now();
};
```

HTML:

```
<span data-bind="textInterval: { cb: getTime, interval: 1000 }"></span>
```

The `textInterval` binding is a custom binding that would essentially invoke the callback at the specified interval and update the node with the returned value. It would also clear the interval on `domNodeDisposal`.

A few things to note:

- The logic for getting the time is actually more complex than shown and belongs in the VM and not the binding
- Unit testing is important to us regardless of the approach

I realize there's not much difference between both approaches but I'm more interested in the most *correct* approach in the Knockout philosophy. When should you move the logic from the VM to a custom binding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html) says

> [Creating a custom binding] is how to control how observables interact
>   with DOM elements, and gives you a lot of flexibility to encapsulate
>   sophisticated behaviors in an easy-to-reuse way.

Use a custom binding when you need to tell Knockout how you want it to interact with a DOM element. This is typically for things like widgets provided by other toolkits or specialized widgets you want to create yourself. If you don't need to manipulate the DOM element, you probably don't need a custom binding.